# Finding the p-values for one sample t-test in different cases

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, inference, p-value, central-limit-theorem

Calculate and interpret the $p-$ value in the following situations:
(a) one-sample $t$ - test for testing
(i) $H_{0}: \mu=\mu_{0}$ vs $H_{1}: \mu \neq \mu_{0}$
(ii) $H_{0}: \mu \leq \mu_{0}$ vs $H_{1}: \mu>\mu_{0}$
(iii) $H_{0}: \mu \geq \mu_{0}$ vs $H_{1}: \mu<\mu_{0}$
when $n=10$ and the observed value
$$
t_{\mathrm{obs}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{x}_{n}-\mu_{0}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}_{n}\right)^{2}}}=2.2
$$
(b) the same setting but with a test based on the CLT-approximation of the distribution of $t_{\text {obs }}$
(c) likelihood ratio test when the observed value of the test statistic is 10 and there are
(i) 1 ,
(ii) 5 ,
(iii) 10
degrees of freedom.

---

I have just started to study P-vlaue (from Cassella and Berger), I am having difficulty in solving this problem.

For the part (a) using following steps I think I can find the required p value:

1. Calculate the sample mean.
   $\overline{x}\ =\ \frac{x_1\ +\ x_2\ +\ \cdots\ +\ x_n}{n}$
2. Calculate the sample standard deviation.
   $\hat{\sigma}\ =\ \sqrt{\frac{(x_1\ -\ \overline{x})^2\ +\ (x_2\ -\ \overline{x})^2\ +\ \cdots\ +\ (x_n\ -\ \overline{x})^2}{n\ -\ 1}}$
3. Calculate the test statistic.
   $t\ =\ \frac{\overline{x}\ -\ m_0}{\hat{\sigma}/\sqrt{n}}$
4. Calculate the probability of observing the test statistic under the null hypothesis. This value is obtained by comparing t to a t-distribution with $(n\ -\ 1)$ degrees of freedom. This can be done by looking up the value in a table, such as those found in many statistical textbooks, or with statistical software for more accurate results.
   $p\ =\ 2\ \cdot\ Pr(T\ >\ |t|)$    (two-tailed)
   $p\ =\ Pr(T\ >\ t)$    (upper-tailed)
   $p\ =\ Pr(T\ <\ t)$    (lower-tailed)

But I have no idea how to calculate p-values in case for part (b) and part (c).
Any hint or suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: for part (a) your steps are correct. For (b), you bring a small change in step 4. Instead of checking t-table, you check table for standard normal distribution (as that this is the asymptotic distribution of the t-statistic under null hypothesis). For part (c), the question has already given the test statistic ($-2\ln \lambda$) which asymptotically follows $\chi^2_q$; where values of $q$ are already specified. So again, you just need to see the table for chi-squared distribution for specified degrees of freedom.